# Frustrated because used standard R addition formula for mechanics problem, but the answer came out wrong. How to resolve this so doesn't happen again?

Tags: trigonometry

In the middle of quite a lengthy mechanics problem, I got to:

$$\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha = 0.05\ $$

and I wanted to find the value of $\ \alpha,\ 0<\alpha<90^{\circ}\ $ that satisfies this equation using an R addition formulae, as that is the usual way to go here.

So I tried:

$$\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha = R\sin\left(\alpha+\gamma\right) = R\sin\alpha\cos\gamma\  + R\cos\alpha\sin\gamma $$

$$\implies R\cos\gamma = -1\quad \text{and}\quad R\sin\gamma = 1$$

$$\implies R^2 = 2\quad \text{and}\quad \tan\gamma = -1$$

At this point, I usually assume $R>0$ and $0<\gamma<90^{\circ}\ $ will give the correct evaluation of $\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha\ $, but that is not the case here.

In fact the correct evaluation of $\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha\ $ is:

$\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha\ = -\sqrt{2}\sin(\alpha-45^{\circ}).\ $

So I got the answer wrong because I didn't even think to check if $R$ and $\gamma$ were correct because like I said, I just assumed  $R>0$ and $0<\gamma<90^{\circ}\ $ should always work.

But when I get to

$$\implies R^2 = 2\quad \text{and}\quad \tan\gamma = -1$$

in my working, I don't want to check the four combinations: $\ R = \pm \sqrt{2}\ $ and
$\ \left( \gamma = -45^{\circ}\ \text{or}\ \gamma = 135^{\circ}\ \right).$

So instead of having to check these four options every time, what is a quicker way of ensuring I get to the right answer every time? Probably I should use a different R addition formula for this circumstance, but I don't know a good summary of which R addition formula I should use for each of the different circumstances...

Comment: One way to avoid the error here is to first solve a simpler problem: what value you’d need for $\alpha$ to get 0 instead of 0.05. Given the range of allowed angles, this tells you that $\alpha\approx 45^\circ$. Since the cosine is slightly larger than the sine, the correct angle is slightly less than 45 degrees. This suggests the substitution $\beta =45^\circ-\alpha$ with the solution being a small positive angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure that $\gamma$ is acute and $R>0$ you just have to choose the correct one of four compound angle identities.

Choose whichever one starts with the first function and has the correct $+$ or $-$ sign.

In your example you have $\color{red}{\cos}\alpha\color{red}{-}\sin\alpha$ therefore choose

$$\cos(\alpha+\gamma)=\color{red}{\cos}\alpha\cos\gamma\color{red}{-}\sin\alpha\sin\gamma$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   \cos\alpha - \sin\alpha &= \frac{1}{20}\\
   \cos\alpha \cdot \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} -\sin\alpha\cdot \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} 
   &= \frac{\sqrt 2}{40}\\
   \cos\alpha \cdot \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) 
  -\sin\alpha \cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) 
   &= \frac{\sqrt 2}{40}\\
   \cos\left(\alpha + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) &= \frac{\sqrt 2}{40}\\
   \alpha + \frac{\pi}{4} &=\arccos \frac{\sqrt 2}{40} \\
   \text{and so on}
\end{align}

Another example

\begin{align}
   5\cos\alpha - 7\sin\alpha &=  z\\
   \frac{5}{\sqrt{74}}\cos\alpha - \frac{7}{\sqrt{74}}\sin\alpha 
      &= \frac{z}{\sqrt{74}}\\
\end{align}

$$\left\{\text{Let $\cos \beta = \frac{5}{\sqrt{74}}$ and 
$\sin \beta = \frac{7}{\sqrt{74}}$}\right\}$$

\begin{align}
   \cos\alpha \cos \beta - \sin\alpha \sin \beta
      &= \frac{z}{\sqrt{74}}\\
\cos(\alpha + \beta) &= \frac{z}{\sqrt{74}}\\
&\cdots
\end{align}

Comment: That's a nice method for this particular problem, but your method isn't related to the general method of the R addition formulae, which is what my question is about.

Comment: @AdamRubinson It is exactly the R addition formula from the other direction.

Comment: My point is that it would be difficult to apply your exact method to say, $\ 5\cos\alpha - 7\sin\alpha$

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Thanks for updating your answer to include a second example.